# How do I disable the Android Logcat popup?

Tags: android-studio, logcat

How do I disable the Android Logcat popup whenever I launch an app in Android Studio? I use the terminal to check logcat and it is irritating to have to close it each time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Logcat (DDMS) & Run Console automatically opening on any activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451828/disable-logcat-ddms-run-console-automatically-opening-on-any-activity)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run -> Edit Configurations -> Select your application -> Logcat tab -> Uncheck *Show logcat automatically*

[image: Do not show logcat automatically]