# Disable Logcat (DDMS) & Run Console automatically opening on any activity

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, ddms

I monitor my logcat from outside Android Studio ([logcat-color](https://github.com/marshall/logcat-color) open beside my emulator on another screen/workspace) and would like to stop the Android DDMS view from opening within Android Studio automatically. It takes up screen real estate that I'd prefer to keep for my code.

I know that I can remove the view entirely but I'd like to retain access to it for the times that I use it for linking directly to a problematic line of code quickly.
I can filter the logcat output to only show 'error' level but that isn't a great solution as I'd be constantly changing filters to get at the surrounding log entries if there were a problem I wanted to trace.

The same is true of the Run Console. I'd like to stop it opening too.

Is there a way to have access to these two views without them opening any time there's activity? I've looked through the settings but can't find any likely candidates to modify.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First, to get rid of the logcat opening on run, go to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...` on the main menu (or via the toolbar dropdown), then uncheck the `Show logcat automatically` option in the `Logcat` tab.

Next, unfortunately there is no way to permanently prevent the run window from popping up when you run, but there is a workaround that mostly does the job once you get used to it.

Basically, when the run window pops up do **NOT** close or minimize it using the buttons, rather resize it down to the bottom (i.e. grab the top of the window and drag down until it is gone). This way, even though it activates when running, it will not show. Clicking on it (once, or sometimes twice) restores it to it's previous size.

Also note that whenever you access one of the tool windows in the same area as the run window it will reset and you will need to resize it down again. Not ideal, but it works okay.

Once you get used to always dragging it down to close it, the run window becomes much less of a pain.

Comment: Thanks. run config change is exactly what I was looking for to sort the logcat view. The run view resize is hacky but also does the job. Fingers crossed the IntelliJ/Android team address the shortcoming.

Comment: I agree, and with the vast amount of control we have in IntelliJ/AS it seems like an oversight that this one thing can not be controlled. Unfortunately "annoyances" like this, which don't cause any harm (except to our sanity), is usually pushed to the very bottom of the todo list in favor of more "important" stuff :(

Comment: Yeah, I've submitted a bug report or two to IntelliJ about other UI issues and never seen a single reply. Obviously not high on their list of priorities. ([My biggest gripe/issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126218))

Comment: Fortunately, it seems like now if `show logcat automatically` is disabled, I no longer see the run window. I'm on Android Studio 2 Preview 5, no idea when this changed.

Answer (score 3):

The tab has changed names since @free3dom's comment. Now go to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...` -> **`Miscellaneous`** tab and untick `Show logcat automatically`.

Logcat is now under the "Android Monitor" window.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is a solution which disables the Run tab altogether

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/75124094/16867144

> In case anyone still struggling with this annoying thing, there is a
> way to disable this annoying popup.
>
> **Note:** this will remove the run tab
> altogether.
>
> [image: Disable run tab]
>
> So basically go to your Run/Debug configuration and Uncheck `Activate tool window` at the bottom. This gets rid of the Run tab.