# How to prevent Android Monitor from automatically opening when I run a project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

This Android Monitor window displays log activity from my phone, so I can see stack trace, etc. when my program crashes. Fortunately my program usually runs without crashing. :-) However this means the window is not useful to me most of the time.

How can I prevent Android Monitor from opening automatically on every time I Run Project?

For now, I've just resized it to be very small.

Comment: you can also close it IMHO. Or simply ignore it (don't look at it), there are enough other tabs that can be displayed over it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Logcat (DDMS) & Run Console automatically opening on any activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451828/disable-logcat-ddms-run-console-automatically-opening-on-any-activity)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For Android Studio 1.4

1. go to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations`
2. expand `Defaults` and click on `Android Application` (or just for the current app, pick the top `Android Application` node)
3. switch to `Miscellaneous` tab
4. uncheck the `Show logcat automatically` option

You can open the window anytime by `Alt/Opt+6`.

Answer (score 0):

As this answer says: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24459915/4409113

> to get rid of the `logcat opening` on run, go to `Run` -> `Edit`
>   `Configurations`... on the `main menu` (or via the toolbar dropdown), then
>   **uncheck** the `Show logcat automatically option` in the `Logcat` tab.

**Similar question:** [Disable Logcat (DDMS) & Run Console automatically opening on any activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451828/disable-logcat-ddms-run-console-automatically-opening-on-any-activity)

Comment: The "Run" window is not the same as the "Android Monitor" which the OP is asking about.

Comment: Says:  `on every time I Run Project`, check the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24459915/4409113 and it was about the same as the another user mentioned about: `Show logcat automatically`

Comment: "How can I prevent **Android Monitor** from opening automatically" The "Android Monitor" window shows the logcat. On the other hand, "Run" shows other output like test results for JUnit tests.

Comment: Actually, yes, you're right but when says on `every time I Run Project` i just mentioned about the link with the first part about that `Show logcat automatically`.btw, fixed.